# Injecting viewmodel to view with MEF - Binding from source not working - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I'm injecting my viewmodel to my view using the MEF container like below:

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainView(IRepository repository, MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mMainViewModel = viewModel;
        DataContext = viewModel;
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;
    }
```

Everything works fine. I have the export attribute on both the view and viewmodel.

The problem is that when a value\property is updated on the ViewModel by some method, it does not reflect on the UI. I even tried to set Mode to Two way - still not working. I have `OnPropertyChanged` called for all property setters, but not working. HOWEVER, in the code behind for the view though, if I attach a `propertychanged` event method to the viewmodel, I get the event notifications and that is the only way I'm able to update the view using their but that should not be necessary. I just don't know why my view is not responding to `propertychanged` notifications directly on the bound elements.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to inject anything into the view by contructor? There is no valid reason for that when dealing with MVVM. Your base concept is wrong

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by base concept is wrong? I know I can do either constructor injection or property injection. In the case of the views, I chose constructor injection so I can set the DataContext. What's wrong with the approach? thanks.

Comment: Have a look at MVVMlight how they bind the MainViewModel to the MainView (It is done inside XAML). And what is the reason for injecting the repository to the View?

Comment: I'm using MEF not MVVMLIGHT where there's a viewlocator...

Comment: Please provide your VM code.

Comment: Found the issue. Turned out that in my abstract ViewModelBase class, I had the functions for notifypropertychanged...But I didn't have the INotifyPropertyChanged on the class name although I implemented the method..stupid mistake. Must have missed it. Brings up another question...why must we have the interface definition on the class for it to work?...well, all is good now. works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Turned out that in my abstract ViewModelBase class, I had the functions for notifypropertychanged...But I didn't have the INotifyPropertyChanged on the class name although I implemented the method..stupid mistake. Must have missed it. Brings up another question...why must we have the interface definition on the class for it to work?...well, all is good now. works fine now.

Comment: The WPF binding does not look if the class has an event PropertyChanged, it just query if the class implements INotifyPropertyChanged